# Conversion to Python 3 using 2to3 (and UTF-8)

Tags: utf-8, python-3.x

I'm given a task of converting a bunch of code written in Python 2 to Python 3,
and this task was given with emphasis on having UTF-8 (didn't quite comprehend the concept but anyway..)

I've automated the conversion using 2to3, but not sure if using 2to3 achieves the goal of having UTF-8, or if there's some other parts that I should manually work on.

What is it exactly, and is it done automatically by using 2to3?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe you should clarify yourself what the requirement of "having UTF-8" means exactly. Otherwise this is kinda of hard to answer for anybody here.

Comment: that's what i'm not sure about.... I was just told the importance of converting it into Python 3 due to importance of UTF-8 so that the program can work with any other language

Comment: Then please clarify the requirements with whoever told you this. "UTF-8 support" can happen in many different locations throughout an app. Maybe you want to read some of the articles I wrote at http://kunststube.net to get an idea of what you're talking about...

Comment: the program works this way: the user makes a library of pre-defined facts, and then enters a new fact to validate it based on pre-defined facts... Could this get the problem a little clearer?

Comment: In Python 3 strings are Unicode strings by default; in ealier versions they weren't, except when using the `u` prefix. So I'm guessing they're asking you to make sure all the string processing is Unicode aware. The standard library should be fine, but many third party modules that work just fine with ASCII break with UTF-8.

Comment: I suggest this article on Unicode: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"I was just told the importance of converting it into Python 3 due to importance of UTF-8 so that the program can work with any other language"*

Whoever told you that was misinformed.

2to3 does not do anything towards "having UTF-8" whatever that means. 2to3 is to move your code from Python 2 to Python 3. Python 3 does mean you have have Unicode variable names, but I would strongly recommend against that anyway. Bad Idea. Otherwise Python 2 supports Unicode and UTF-8 perfectly well.

It seems your actual goal is not UTF-8, but translating the program to other language, also known as internationalization, or "18n". That's a completely different issue, and has nothing to do with 2to3. Instead you need to manually change all your text strings to gettext tokens that will be translated when rendered. See http://docs.python.org/library/gettext.html

See also http://regebro.wordpress.com/2011/03/23/unconfusing-unicode-what-is-unicode/ for more information on Unicode.